# Scraping a table made of tables in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a table from a website I am trying to download, and it appears to be made of a bunch of tables.  Right now I am using `rvest` to bring the table in as text, but it is bringing in a bunch of other tables I am not interested in and then I am coercing the data into a better format, but it's not a repeatable process.  Here is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)

#Auto Download Data
#reads the url of the race
race_url <- read_html("http://racing-reference.info/race/2016_Folds_of_Honor_QuikTrip_500/W") 
#reads in the tables, in this code there are too many
race_results <- race_url %>%
        html_nodes(".col") %>%
        html_text() 
race_results <- data.table(race_results) #turns from a factor to a DT
f <- nrow(race_results) #counts the number of rows in the data
#eliminates all rows after 496 (11*45 + 1) since there are never more than 43 racers
race_results <- race_results[-c(496:f)] 
#puts the data into a format with 1:11 numbering for unstacking
testDT <- data.frame(X = race_results$race_results, ind = rep(1:11, nrow(race_results)/11)) 
testDT <- unstack(testDT, X~ind) #unstacking data into 11 columns
colnames(testDT) <- testDT[1, ] #changing the top column into the header
```

I commented everything so you would know what I am trying to do.  If you go to the URL, there is a top table with driver results, which is what I am trying to scrape, but it is pulling the bottom ones too, as I can't seem to get a different `html_nodes` to work other than with ".col".  I also tried `html_table()` in place of the `html_text()` but it didn't work.  I suppose this can be done either by identifying the table in the css (I can't figure this out) or by using a different type of call or the XML library (which I also can't figure out).  Any help or direction is appreciated.

UPDATE:

From the comments below, the correct code to pull this data is as follows:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)

#Auto Download Data
race_url <- read_html("http://racing-reference.info/race/2016_Folds_of_Honor_QuikTrip_500/W") #reads the url of the race
race_results <- race_url %>% html_nodes("table") #returns a DF with all of the tables on the page
race_results <- race_results[7] %>% html_table()
race_results <- data.frame(race_results) #turns from a factor to a DT
```

Comment: try using:  `race_results <- race_url %>%  html_nodes("table")`  Now race_results is a list of all of the tables on the page.  Figure out which table you are interested in and you are all set.  Be sure to follow the terms of service for this website.

Comment: Using the suggestion from @Dave2e you should find that `race_results[7] %>% html_table()` returns what you want.

Comment: Thank you both!  I updated the question to reflect the correct code above.